# Menu transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm trying to rebuild not copy and paste this website http://paramoredigital.com/ only for learning direction. I have problem with menu transition, more precisely If you click top-right button menu will show up smoothly and I don't know how to do it in my code.

Here is my code https://github.com/Szuchow/paramore-digital.

Comment: Post your code here and explain what your problem is more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the X and the menu will appear. The rest is a matter of styling.

```js
$("body").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu").addClass("open");
})
```

```css
body {
padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: pink;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu.open {
  opacity: 1;
}

.toggle a {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="toggle"><a href="#">X</a></span>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```